# Android-JVM universal logger

Tags: java, android, logging

My Android library consists of pure Java core and Android-specific surrounding code.
I have local unit-test (JVM) and instrumentation test (Android).
Is there a universal logger library which allows to use `java.lang.System.out.println()` if running on JVM and `android.util.Log` if running on Android?